# Systemd service will not start by itself on boot

Tags: systemd

here's my systemd script:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service for controling amdgpu fan.
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/amdgpu-fan
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It runs fine when starting it manually with `systemctl start amdgpu-fan.service`.

I have done `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo systemctl enable` and confirm on reboot it is enabled by looking at `sudo systemctl list-unit-files`.  However despite this, if I do `ps aux | grep amdgpu-fan` it is certainly not running and my graphics card is of course at risk of overheating.

Unsure what the snafu is, help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it failed to start? Try `systemctl status amdgpu-fan.service`.

Comment: Try using `sudo journalctl -xe --unit=amdgpu-fan.service` for a more detailed log.

Comment: Ah this was helpful. It seems like there is a race condition.  The amdgpu-fan utility isn't finding a compatible card so it exits with failure.  Doing several reboots it seems hit/miss.  Is there a better "After" condition I should be using?

Comment: Perhaps after the kernel has loaded up other modules? You could try: `After=syslog.target systemd-modules-load.service`